# How to remove get parameters from prettyPhoto URL

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

i want to open an iframe with prettyPhoto and would like to optimize the URL

```
<a href="iframe.html?iframe=true&width=100&height=100">
```

I tried to add a class to the link and pass the arguments via jQuery but that doesnt work.

```
    $("a.iframe']").prettyPhoto({
        iframe: true, 
        width: '100%', 
        height: '100%'
    });
```

So is there a way to get rid of those params in the url?

Answer (score 0):

prettyPhoto allows you to set the default width/height like this:

```
$("a.iframe']").prettyPhoto({
  default_width: 100,
  default_height: 100
});
```

The docs dont allow any other option to set those dimentions.
you can read the [docs and see the full list of options here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much idea about this prettyPhoto js. But I think you did not give the class name to anchor link, so jQuery function was not called in you code. please the replace the anchor link by the below anchor link.

```
<a href="iframe.html?iframe=true&width=100&height=100" class="iframe">
```

Thanks,
Amit Prajapati